# Updating specific records by using a id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i'm new to codeigniter. I need to update records by using an id. i did my part but that's not updating. i attached the codes below. and i need to update the image also. i confused updating an image. please help me to update the image too. i would happy if you take consider about this question.

**my view page**

```
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <h1 class="page-header">Update Article</h1>

            <?php foreach ($article as $row ) {

            }?>

           <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/article/update_save" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<?php echo $row->art_title; ?>">
                <label for="name">Description</label>
                <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" name="desc"><?php echo $row->art_desc; ?></textarea>
                <label for="title">Image</label>
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assests/img/<?php echo $row->art_img; ?>"/>
                </a>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="upload">
                <br/>
                <div align="right">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
                  <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Reset">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**this is my controller**

```
function update_article(){

    $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array();
    $data['article'] = $this->article_m->show_update_m($id);

    $this->load->view('update_article', $data);
}

function update_save(){

    $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $data_update = array(

        'art_title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'art_desc' => $this->input->post('desc')

        );

    //print_r($data_update);

    $this->article_m->do_update_m($id, $data_update);
    $this->edit_article();

}
```

**this is my model**

```
function show_update_m($id){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('front_article');
    $this->db->where('art_id' ,$id);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}


function do_update_m($id, $data_update){

    $this->db->where('art_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('front_article', $data_update);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

as i see in your code you didn't send the id from view:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>**index.php/article/update_save**" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
```

then what would be the $id in your controller?:

```
$id=$this->uri->segment(3);
```

try this:
put this in your form in view:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row->id?>" />
```

and get the id in your controller by this:

```
 $id = $this->input->post('id');
```